# File transfer being handled by a different program

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer

First of all, i'd like to say that i'm not sure that i'm asking this question in the correct section, as i don't know exactly what my problem is.

I've never had this issue before but, after copy and pasting files from directory to directory i noticed that the file transfer wasn't the usual Windows 10 one, it now looks a lot different and the window was named "TurboPC EX FileCopy - Copying files...", i have no clue as to what could've caused this.

I couldn't seem to find any previous questions regarding this so, i decided to ask here.

Comment: Is it: "BUFFALO TurboPC EX" maybe?  If you look in Programs and Features (appwiz.cpl) do you see an application from BUFFALO you might want to uninstall?

Comment: The window name doesn't contain "BUFFALO" but yes, i'm pretty sure that's it.

After looking in "Apps & Features" as you recommended, i found "BUFFALO TurboPC EX Series" but, i don't want to uninstall it, i'd rather just change what file transfering is using.